Website Dimensions not making sense - Laptop VIew

I'm a web developer and I'm working a website. I was viewing the dimensions for it on a
macbook laptop. According to Google Chrome Developer the dimensions for the webpage is 1420 x
373, which would mean the site height is 373px. That doesn't make sense to be because if a site
height was only 373px on a laptop version the page height would be really short. Can someone
help me or explain what these dimensions mean? I have a screenshot attached so you can have a
visual of what I'm saying.

You can adjust the size by dragging the bottom right corner of the screen. The dimensions are correct, as you can see that the inspect element covers half the screen, and the screen size is reduced. You can open the inspect tool in a new window to see the full view of your screen.

Thank you so much. I appreciate it.
